# Google Adwords API ad schedule criterion ID

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I am writing a script that automatically sets the ad schedule times for multiple campaigns at once.

The body of the API Call is the following.

The problem is that I get this error:

> WebFault: Server raised fault: '[RequiredError.REQUIRED @ operations[0].operand.criterion.id]'

Obviously, the criterion ID is missing.

What should the criterion ID look like?

```
# create adschedule
adschedule = {
    'xsi_type': 'AdSchedule',
    'dayOfWeek': 'TUESDAY',
    'startHour': "0",
    'endHour': "22",
    'startMinute': "FIFTEEN",
    'endMinute': "FORTY_FIVE"
}

# Create operation
operation = {
    'operator': 'SET',
    'operand': {
        "campaignId": campaignId,
        "criterion": adschedule
    }
}

# Make the mutate request.
result = campaign_criterion_service.mutate(operation)
```

Comment: Improved grammar and formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a new ad schedule, use `ADD` as an operator instead of `SET`. As `AdSchedule`s are immutable (I think all criteria are), you cannot modify them.

If modifying is what you actually want to do, you need to delete the existing `AdSchedule` and create a new one. You can retrieve the IDs of existing schedules by calling the CampaignCriterionService's `get` method, this could look something like this:

```
campaign_criterion_service.get({
    'fields': ['Id', 'DayOfWeek', 'StartHour', 'StartMinute', 'EndHour', 'EndMinute'],
    'predicates': [{
        'field': 'CriteriaType',
        'operator': 'EQUALS',
        'values': ['AD_SCHEDULE']
    }]
})
```